# Use \normalsize with \SetWatermarkFontSize

Tags: fontsize, draftwatermark

I use a package that generates watermarks, its name is `draftwatermark`. The package offers options or commands to set its properties. One of the properties is the size of the watermark text in units of length (e.g. 12pt). However, I don't want to set the length with an explicit value (e.g. 12pt), but I want to use the document's `\normalsize` length instead. I wrote:

```
\SetWatermarkFontSize{\normalsize}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I set this value to match the document's \normalsize?

Comment: As a former user of `draftwatermark` and `xwatermark`, I would suggest [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) as a better package to watermarks.

Comment: @FHZ, I'll check these packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\normalsize` is an internal command that sets the font size to either 10pt, 11pt or 12pt (plus a few additional things like  `\abovedisplayskip`) etc.

`\SetWatermarkFontSize`, on the other hand, expects a value, not a command. If you don't want to use something like `12pt` (why not?), you can use a relative value, like `0.25\paperwidth` or, if you want to base it on the font size, something like `1em`.

```
\SetWatermarkFontSize{1.15em}
```

Comment: So `1em` equals \normalsize? I can't use explicit value because this is part of a document class that I create for LyX. And LyX sets the font sizes through a UI which I can't predict.

Comment: An `em` is a unit in the field of typography equal to the currently specified point size, yes.